# ASPasswordCredential - from where?

Tags: swift, icloud, keychain, apple-sign-in

When using Sign in with Apple there's an `ASPasswordCredential` option which will pull the password from the iCloud keychain.  I can't find details though on "where" in the keychain you store things.  i.e. how do I know what keys to store the user or password details under.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be connected with Password Auto Fill, which is available since iOS 12 (see section Password-Based Login inside https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices).
So if your app already has this functionality you could associate existing users with their new Apple ID accounts.

Comment: tried recently. Password Autofill works like if you input your password manually. The only info I found: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4875322-sign-in-with-apple-using-swiftui `The other possibility, when using Sign In with Apple, is the end user will select credentials which are already stored in the iCloud keychain for the site.`

Comment: The most funny thing is that raywenderlich tutorial's author linked by @VyachaslavGerchicov is the one who asked this question! :D